# How to convert list of dict values to tuple in python 3.4.4?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a dict of lists like this:

```
l = [{'d':1},{'d':2}]
```

the output i want is tuple of dict values as:

```
t = (1,2)
```

I have tried for loop
but is there any better solution? any builtin function ?
I want the best pythonic way to do this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, I'll try and make it more pythonic...

```
l = [{'d':1},{'d':2},{'d':1},{'d':2}]
vals = []
for d in l:
    vals.extend(d.values())
print(tuple(vals))
```

As a list comprehension (1.08 usec per loop):

```
tuple(item for sublist in l for item in sublist.values())
```

With `reduce` (This wont with more than two dicts) (2.06 usec per loop):

```
l = [{'d':1},{'d':2}]
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: tuple(x.values()) + tuple(y.values()),l)
```

To handle more than two dicts we have to prep the first value of the list so it's already a `tuple` (2.06 usec per loop):

```
from functools import reduce
l[0] = tuple(l[0].values())
reduce(lambda x,y: x + tuple(y.values()) ,l)
```

And if you were desperate for a single line (2.56 usec per loop):

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: tuple(x.values() if isinstance(x, dict) else x) + tuple(y.values()),l)
```

Now with `map` and `itertools` (2.74 usec per loop):

```
from itertools import chain
tuple(chain(*map(lambda x: tuple(x.values()), l))))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Darkstarone provides a lot of helpful methods, of which the fastest and I think most pythonic is the one with list comprehension. I found the double list comprehension a little confusing, so I came up with a solution that only involves a single list comprehension (admittedly, with a little more bulk in other places).

```
tuple([list(a.values())[0] for a in l])
```